# Merge "left-luggage" and "luggage-storage" tags

Tags: discussion, tagging, tag-synonyms

So, there's a semi-popular (and obvious what it means) tag, [luggage-storage](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/luggage-storage). There's also a much less common tag (and easily confused with lost luggage, even if it is the idiomatic (British English) term) [left-luggage](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/left-luggage).

I can't see any reason to have both. Merge down to [luggage-storage](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/luggage-storage) I think.

Comment: I would agree with that suggestion (as a non-native speaker). Is it just me or does luggage storage carry something more long-term than left-luggage?

Comment: @mts It does, but I don't think that distinction is so important that they need whole separate tags. I can't really imagine people thinking "Ugh, I followed this tag because I wanted to see questions about storing luggage for periods of up to around a week, but *this* question's about storing luggage for *two* weeks! That sort of thing wouldn't interest me at all!"

Comment: [tag:left-luggage] makes me think of luggage for left handed people, or/and as you said lost luggage. I seriously wouldn't ***ever*** think it meant luggage storage. British English is f u n

Comment: I agree with your suggestion, they seem too similar to justify the tag difference. Especially considering that the questions it contains are mostly about storing luggage.

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like people are in favour, so, if you've got "more than 2500 reputation and a total answer score of 5 or more on the tag", head to https://travel.stackexchange.com/tags/luggage-storage/synonyms and hit the tiny little up arrow next to left-luggage to vote for it becoming a synonym of luggage-storage.

*(if you do passionately believe the difference between left luggage and luggage storage is wide enough that two different tags are necessary, you can vote it down there)*

Answer (score 1):

[We have a tag rename question.](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3914/september-2016-tag-rename-synonym-megaquestion) Post this request there and it'll be handled by moderators. Relying on tag synonyms is borderline utopian.

Comment: One more vote and we can do it ourselves. Hail utopia!